# 14.0 LTS to 16.04 LTS error

Tags: 14.04, upgrade

I got a pop-up window asking if I want to upgrade from 14.04 to the newest version of Ubuntu.  I agreed, and clicked through a couple clicks and then it errored out saying dependency not installed apt(>= 1.0.1ubuntu2.13) or something like that.  There is nothing remarkable about my install or my machine.  Can anyone help me out with the error?  Sorry I don't have the exact wording, the pop-up went away....

Comment: Same question: [Missing dependency for Ubuntu 16.04 upgrade](http://askubuntu.com/q/806164)

Answer (score 1):

I would try

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and check if there are any dependencies not met or for any other errors.

sudo apt-get dist-upgrade is another solution as well (check what the difference between these commands are).