# Missing dependency for Ubuntu 16.04 upgrade

Tags: apt, upgrade, dependencies

When I attempted to  upgrade from Ubuntu 14.04  to 16.04, the upgrade stopped and I received the following message:

```
Required depends is not installed 
The required dependency 'apt (>= 1.0.1ubuntu2.13)' is not installed.
```

[image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: Same question: [14.0 LTS to 16.04 LTS error](http://askubuntu.com/q/806154)

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu 14.04, open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade apt
```

Afterwards running this command in Ubuntu 14.04:

```
apt-cache policy apt
```

Should produce these results:

```
apt:
  Installed: 1.0.1ubuntu2.14
  Candidate: 1.0.1ubuntu2.14
```

If the first command doesn't work, the long version is:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt full-upgrade # in 14.04 use sudo apt-get dist-upgrade instead
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade apt
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Comment: @RayWalker If it worked, please click the checkmark to mark the answer as accepted :)

Comment: I Ran the long version of the command and got this result, again.
 
The required dependency 'apt (>= 1.0.1ubuntu2.13)' is not installed.

Answer (score 0):

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/ says that 1.0.1ubuntu2.13 is in the security repositories and 1.0.1ubuntu2.14 is in the updates repositories.
Maybe you need to check your sources.

Comment: Now, I'm lost. Can I have guidance on getting 1.0.1ubuntu2.14 and installing it?